# Unexpected behavior in keys() redis python module using NULL & ETX sequence

Tags: redis, redis-py

I'm using redis with the python module to save byte sequence (as keys)
When i'm trying to get keys contains: "\x00??\x03" (? = any ASCII character)

for example:

str = "\x00\x01\x00\x03" (as byte sequence)

db.keys(pattern='*'+str+'*')

gives me all the keys.

Is this a normal behavior?